# Jquery Datatable Invalid Json Response Error

Tags: jquery, json, model-view-controller, datatables

This is my action result where i get the data. I have no clue why this happens everything looks fine.

```
public ActionResult loadProjectData()
    {

        var data = harvestApi.GetAllProject2().OrderBy(a => a.created_at).ToList() ;

        return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is my DataTable funciton

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/project/loadProjectData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json",

                },
                "iDisplayLength": 100,

                "columns": [
                        {
                            "data": "harvestLink", "autoWidth": true, "bSortable": true, "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                                return '<a targevt="_blank" href=' + data +
                                     '>' + full.name + '</a>';

                            }
                        },


                        {
                            "data": "Client_Id", "autoWidth": true, "bSortable": true, "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                                return '<a target="_blank" href=' +
                                     '@Url.Action("Customercard", "Customer")?id=' + data +
                                     '>' + full.c+ '</a>';
                            },
                        },
           ]

                });
              });
```

JSON:
[image: JSON]

Comment: Can you post what your JSON that is actually sent to the page in plaintext? Your browser console or Fiddler can help to find that data. It's not easy to tell if your JSON is valid from the Visual Studio watch of the data.

Comment: @ChrisH. how do i watch the sent Json in the web browser, thanks for the insight.

Comment: Like I said, it will be in your browser console (I'm not sure where, I use a plugin that overrides my console) or if you download Fiddler you can use that to listen in. There's a guide [here](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7)

Comment: Dude seriously, thank you very much!! the problem was a property was returning -Infinity as a value which is not a valid json response. how can i upvote you!